# How use Binance Api to receive USDT in app

Tags: cryptocurrency, binance, tether

I need to Use Binance API to generate USDT address per order and track it.
I just need to use the Binance wallet, not any exchange service but not find it.

Comment: Hi frank, are you able to solve this challenge

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible with Binance API.